# How to cover delete part in testclass

Tags: unit-test

In  test class,Following Lines are not covering.

***Attachment:***

[image]

But I need to cover Those two lines as well.I'am doing some mistake for covering those two lines, can anyone Please help me to cover those two lines. (Test class has already have sufficient code coverage but I need to learn what Iam missing)

***Background:***

Before creating "Prospectassementranking" its clearing the existing prospect assesment ranking values on linked Opportunity.

We are creating prospect assesment ranking based on Opportunity Buisness and Propect assesment criteria.

```
  public static void insertProjectAssessmentRankingIfNULL(List<Opportunity> opList){
    set<id>OpportunityIds=new set<id>();
    set<id> DelOppId=new set<id>();
    map<id,integer> OppMap=new map<id,integer>();
    List<Opportunity>OpportunityList1=new List<Opportunity>();
    set<string> OppBuisnessGroup=new set<string>();
    for(Opportunity op:opList){
        if(op.Business_Group__c!=null){
            OppBuisnessGroup.add(op.Business_Group__c);
            OpportunityIds.add(op.id);
        }
    }

    List<Prospect_Assessment_Criteria__c> ProspectAssessmentList=[SELECT Assigned_Weight_Overall__c,Criteria__c,LOB__c FROM Prospect_Assessment_Criteria__c WHERE LOB__c IN:OppBuisnessGroup];
    if(ProspectAssessmentList.size() > 0)
    {
       List<Opportunity> OpportunityList=[select id,(select id,Opportunity__c from Prospect_Assessment_Rankings__r) from Opportunity where id in:OpportunityIds];
   //checking size
        for(Opportunity op:OpportunityList){
            OppMap.put(op.id,op.Prospect_Assessment_Rankings__r.size());
        }

        for(Opportunity op1:opList){
            if(OppMap.get(op1.id)>0){
                DelOppId.add(op1.id);
            }
        }

        list<Prospect_Assessment_Ranking__c> prospectAssesmentList=[Select ID,Opportunity__c from Prospect_Assessment_Ranking__c where Opportunity__c IN:DelOppId];
        //deleting Prospect Assesment
        if(!prospectAssesmentList.isEmpty()){
            delete prospectAssesmentList;
        }
    }

    Map<string, List<Prospect_Assessment_Criteria__c>> ProjectAssesmentMap = new Map<string, List<Prospect_Assessment_Criteria__c>>();
    List<Prospect_Assessment_Ranking__c> ProjectAssessmentRankList=new List<Prospect_Assessment_Ranking__c>();
    for(Opportunity op:opList){
        if(op.Business_Group__c!=null){
            OppBuisnessGroup.add(op.Business_Group__c);

        }
    }

    List<Prospect_Assessment_Criteria__c> ProspectAssessmentList1=[SELECT Assigned_Weight_Overall__c,Criteria__c,LOB__c FROM Prospect_Assessment_Criteria__c WHERE LOB__c IN:OppBuisnessGroup];

    for( Prospect_Assessment_Criteria__c pr:ProspectAssessmentList1){

        if(!ProjectAssesmentMap.containskey(pr.LOB__c)){
            ProjectAssesmentMap.put(pr.LOB__c,new List<Prospect_Assessment_Criteria__c>{pr});
        }
        else
        {
            ProjectAssesmentMap.get(pr.LOB__c).add(pr);
        }
    }

    List<Prospect_Assessment_Criteria__c> NewProspectAssessmentList=new List<Prospect_Assessment_Criteria__c>();
    for(Opportunity op:opList)
    if(!ProjectAssesmentMap.isEmpty() && ProjectAssesmentMap.containskey(op.Business_Group__c) && ProjectAssesmentMap.get(op.Business_Group__c)!=null){
        NewProspectAssessmentList= ProjectAssesmentMap.get(op.Business_Group__c);
        for(Prospect_Assessment_Criteria__c proAssessment:NewProspectAssessmentList)
        {
            Prospect_Assessment_Ranking__c ProAssessmentRanking=new Prospect_Assessment_Ranking__c();
            ProAssessmentRanking.Assigned_Weight_Overall__c=Decimal.valueof(proAssessment.Assigned_Weight_Overall__c);
            ProAssessmentRanking.Criteria__c=proAssessment.Criteria__c;
            ProAssessmentRanking.Opportunity__c=op.Id;
            ProjectAssessmentRankList.add(ProAssessmentRanking);
        }
    }

    /*Inserting ProjectAssesmentRank if its not null */
    if(!ProjectAssessmentRankList.isEmpty()){
        insert ProjectAssessmentRankList;
    }  

    for(Opportunity op1:[select id,Business_Group_Ranking__c,Business_Group__c from Opportunity where id in:OpportunityIds]){
        if(op1.Business_Group__c!=null){
            op1.Business_Group_Ranking__c=op1.Business_Group__c;
            OpportunityList1.add(op1);
        }
    }

    if(!OpportunityList1.isEmpty()){
        update OpportunityList1;
    }
}
```

---

```
public static testmethod void InsertProjectassementRankingifNULL(){
    Test.startTest();
    Account objAcc=Test_Library.createTestAccount();
    List< Prospect_Assessment_Criteria__c > 
   prospectList=Test_Library.UpdateprospectList();
    Opportunity objOpp=Test_Library.createTestOpportunity2(objAcc);
    objOpp.Business_Group__c='Government';
    update objOpp;
    List<Prospect_Assessment_Ranking__c> prospectRank=[select id,Assigned_Score__c,Criteria__c,Criteria_Score__c,Opportunity__c from Prospect_Assessment_Ranking__c where Opportunity__c=:objOpp.Id];
    System.assertEquals(prospectList.size(),prospectRank.size()); 
    objOpp=[select id,Business_Group_Ranking__c,Business_Group__c from Opportunity where id=:objOpp.Id];
    System.assertEquals(objOpp.Business_Group__c,objOpp.Business_Group_Ranking__c);
    test.stopTest();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick answer

You get coverage for your target lines the same way that you ensure that any other line is covered, by setting up your test environment *so that you are guaranteed to satisfy the conditions to execute your for loops and enter your if blocks*.

### Analysis

Let's focus on the below section of your code

```java
List<Prospect_Assessment_Criteria__c> ProspectAssessmentList=[SELECT Assigned_Weight_Overall__c,Criteria__c,LOB__c FROM Prospect_Assessment_Criteria__c WHERE LOB__c IN:OppBuisnessGroup];

if(ProspectAssessmentList.size() > 0)
{
    List<Opportunity> OpportunityList=[select id,(select id,Opportunity__c from Prospect_Assessment_Rankings__r) from Opportunity where id in:OpportunityIds];

    //checking size
    for(Opportunity op:OpportunityList){
        OppMap.put(op.id,op.Prospect_Assessment_Rankings__r.size());
    }

    for(Opportunity op1:opList){
        if(OppMap.get(op1.id)>0){
            DelOppId.add(op1.id); // This line is uncovered
        }
    }

    list<Prospect_Assessment_Ranking__c> prospectAssesmentList=[Select ID,Opportunity__c from Prospect_Assessment_Ranking__c where Opportunity__c IN:DelOppId];

    //deleting Prospect Assesment
    if(!prospectAssesmentList.isEmpty()){
        delete prospectAssesmentList; // This line is uncovered
    }
}
```

You're entering the `if(prospectAssessmentList.size() > 0)`, and going through your two opportunity loops, so your test setup is creating at least one `Prospect_Assessment_Criteria__c`, and at least one `Opportunity`

You're not entering the `if(OppMap.get(op1.Id) > 0)` block *because no Opportunities that you query have a `Prospect_Assesment_Ranking__c` related to them*

This is causing `delOppId` to remain empty, which causes your `Process_Assesment_Ranking__c` to return 0 rows, which causes you to not satisfy the final if condition to perform your delete DML.

### Conclusion

In the end, this comes down to testing discipline.

Testing has 3 phases: Setup, Execution, and Assertion

In your provided test, your setup is, simply, insufficient. Unless you're strictly adhering to TDD (Test-Driven Development), you should know 100% of the records that you use in the code being tested. *You are responsible for making sure that all of those records exist.*

Add a `Prospect_Assessment_Ranking__c`, and relate it to the `Opportunity` that you're creating, and you should get your coverage.